# Packrat caching : Right to left vs. Left to right?

Tags: algorithm, parsing, peg, packrat

I'm currently trying to familiarize myself with packrat parsing. So I've read the PDF paper from 2002 linked [here](https://bford.info/pub/lang/packrat-icfp02/) and in section 2.3 it describes packrat caching as a preliminary process (which occurs before the actual parsing) in which a full caching table is pre-constructed  by reading the input from right to left. Only then, the actual linear parsing from left to right can start.

But in every PEG parser implementation I found, the "cache" option is usually a caching process that occurs during the actual left to right parsing. For example [here](https://github.com/josephg/miniohm/blob/f530cf54d50404d6723fe2efd42df5b01fd697ce/peg.js).

Is there any difference between both approaches? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently worked on similar research, met the exact same confusion, and resolved it. Regardless if you are still working on this topic, here's my answer.

Your understanding is correct:

- Packrat parser scans input string from **left to right**
- Packrat parser construct the cache from **right to left**

---

But there's just one approach, not two. Let's use one simple example [Parsing Expression Grammar (PEG)](https://bford.info/pub/lang/peg/) without left-recursion: `E -> Num + E | Num`

*(Note that, a left-recursion example requires another long explanation, you can refer [CPython's implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/58fb156edda1a0e924a38bfed494bd06cb09c9a3/Tools/peg_generator/pegen/parser.py#L80) for details)*

The Syntax Directed Translation (SDT) will be something like:

```
E -> a=Num + b=E { a + b }
E -> Num { Num }
```

And we can write a `parse_E` function in below:

```py
def parse_E(idx):
    if idx in cache['parse_E']:
        return cache['parse_E'][idx]

    lval, nidx = parse_Char(idx)
    if nidx < len(self.tokens):
        operator, nnidx = parse_Char(nidx)
        if operator == '+':
            # E -> Num + E
            rval, nnnidx = parse_E(nnidx)
            cache['parse_E'][idx] = lval + rval, nnnidx
            return cache['parse_E'][idx]
    
    # E -> Num
    cache['parse_E'][idx] = lval, nidx
    return cache['parse_E'][idx]
```

According to [Byran Ford's paper](https://pdos.lcs.mit.edu/%7Ebaford/packrat/icfp02/packrat-icfp02.pdf), the parser needs to **scan the input string from left to right** and construct the cache in any position:

```
for idx in len(input_string):
    parse_E(idx)
    parse_Char(idx)
```

So, let's check the cache construction under the hood, initially, we have an empty cache and input string:

```
cache: {'parse_E': {}, 'parse_Char': {}}
input string: `2 + 3 + 4`
```

The function call happens in the following order when `idx=0`. Clearly, we **construct the cache from right to left** at position 0 (not even to mention `idx=1` or above).

- `parse_Char(Y)` happens earlier than `parse_Char(X)` (Y > X)
- `parse_Char(X)` must happens earlier than `parse_E(X)`

```
   parse_E(0)     ---   (E -> Num + E) (pending)
-> parse_Char(0)  --- 2 (pending)
-> parse_Char(1)  --- + (pending)
-> parse_E(2)     --- E (E -> Num + E) (pending)
-> parse_Char(2)  --- 3 (pending)       
-> parse_Char(3)  --- + (pending)
-> parse_E(4)     --- E (E -> Num) (pending)
-> parse_Char(4)  --- 4 (acc)

# Only after parse_Char(4) succeed and fill into cache, parse_E(4) can be successful...and so on.
```

---

If you want to read the full Python example of Packrat parser implementation, you can check [my repository](https://github.com/note35/Parser-Learning). It contains a [handmade Packrat parser](https://github.com/note35/Parser-Learning/blob/main/Packrat/parser_scannerless_with_memo.py) and a [CPython PEG generated Packrat parser](https://github.com/note35/Parser-Learning/blob/main/PEG/basic_calculator_ii.py) based on a [simple meta grammar](https://github.com/note35/Parser-Learning/blob/main/PEG/basic_calculator_ii.python.gram).

Comment: Haha it's been a long time, and when I gave it some more thought, I actually understood the mechanism you describe. I forgot to go back here, but you did it. Thank you!